# ¿Por qué me da error al usar import urllib2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este es mi código:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read ()
print (html)
```

Este es el error que tengo:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
>     import urllib2
> ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Python 3, `urlopen` ha sido movido. Lo que tienes que hacer ahora es:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen('http://python.org/')
```

Esto está especificado en la documentación de [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) para Python 2:

> **Note:** The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in
>   Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

Para un efecto similar a importar `urllib2`
yo usaría:

```
from urllib.request import *
from urllib.error import *
```

Comment: La pregunta ya tiene una respuesta correcta y aceptada.